# Is there a plugin like "mvn search"?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I want to use VIM for Java programing, but I found it is very cumbersome to find and set a Maven dependence at command line.

Is there a plugin to search dependence like "apt-cache search"? and adding a dependence to pom.xml like "apt-get install"?

This should be a basic function, Why there is no such plugin ? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no plugin, and I can't answer why.

However in the IDE I use (IntelliJ) and probably others, there are help pop-ups that ask you if you want to add a dependency to a POM automatically (most likely only for things in your local repository). Also, when editing a POM, anything already in your local repository will autocomplete as you type out the dependency (and if there are multiple versions, the list of versions to choose from is displayed). Just letting you know in case switching to an IDE would help you.

I think the best you can do for search is use a browser off to the side with [MVNRepository](http://mvnrepository.com) loaded up. You can search for libraries and when you see the one you want, you can copy-paste the example dependency into your POM. Note a small fraction of dependencies listed there are not in the most common public repositories and require you to customize your repository list.

Comment: Sonatype have build a search website for Maven central. http://search.maven.org/. It too will display the Maven dependency snippet, which you can copy-n-paste into your POM

Answer (score 0):

[maven dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) could help you a little bit on listing/analyzing dependencies. But it cannot add a dependency for you.

in fact, if you prefer VI to edit files, why not just open pom.xml in your vim, and edit the file directly?

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer working with Vim, you can still do it in Eclipse: try [Vrapper](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/home/) on the free side. On the non-free side, you can try [Viable](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/viable-vim-eclipse) or [viPlugin](http://www.viplugin.com/viplugin/).

Eclipse then has Sonatype's [m2e](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) plugin, which lets you add dependencies and plugins with a sleek search wizard (not to say a whole bunch of other helping features).